# R ggplot: Remove all space around plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I remove all space around the plot area?

Sample data

```
dfr <- data.frame(x=factor(1:5),y=c(3,5,4,2,4))

ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

I tried as below, but there is still space on left and bottom. Bg border colour added to visualise edge.

```
ggplot(dfr,aes(x,y))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  labs(x="",y="")+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_rect(colour="steelblue"),
        plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0),"cm"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `axis.title=element_blank()` to your `theme` statement.

[image]

Comment: A small space remains. The tick marks have been set to `element_blank()`, but a space for the tick marks remains. Add `axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt")` to `theme`. To check: `g=ggplotGrob(p); g$widths; g$heights`

Comment: Another trick I learned recently is to use `+ labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)` intead of `x="",y=""`.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt This is a very useful comment and far from been trivial. I think you should post it as an answer completeing Andrew's one. If you don't I will :) .

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above says, if there's still some frustrating whitespace left, add

```r
theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "pt"))
```

to your plot. This is true even if you've set `axis.ticks = element_blank()`.